# Problem with scrcpy

Tags: android

I tried mirroring my phone on my desktop. So I installed snap version of `scrcpy`, but when I run it from terminal, on my screen the following picture is displayed. Has anyone a clue how to improve the image quality and not see these pixels?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Is your OS Ubuntu Touch?

Comment: no it is my mobile zte. It is not a ubuntu touch. I used snap scrcpy for mirroring my mobile to my desktop. This image is from my laptop's desktop. Can i do something to improve the quality of this window?

Comment: it is android not ubuntu touch

Comment: on my laptop i have ubuntu. This image was appeared on my laptop screen when i used scrcpy.

Comment: Is this issue also present with the apt version of scrcpy?